# Change unit and size and typography in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am working on some statistical tables with tikzpicture and I am unable to solve two situations: a) change the mathematical environment of pgf so that the values ​​of the figure have the same typography as the rest of the table; b) change the unit of measure to Spanish, that is, the point to separate thousand units and the comma to separate decimals.

I leave one of the boxes and the result I get.

Thank you

```
\newcommand*{\cuadrosTTT}{\footnotesize\tt}

\begin{figure}[!ht]\cuadrosTTT
\centering
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=.5pt,linecolor=black,roundcorner=5pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      width=.9\textwidth,
      height=7cm,
      scale only axis,
      legend style={draw=black,legend cell align=left, anchor=north, at={(0.5,-0.13)}},
      enlargelimits=0.1, %controla el tamaño de la caja en la cual estan las barras
      %ylabel={},
      symbolic x coords={1913,1923,1930,1937-8,1944-5,1960,1971},
      xtick=data,
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,},%style={rotate=30, anchor=east, align=center}
      bar width=6mm, %ancho de la barra individual
          %ymin=0, % descomentá si queres ver desde cero
      nodes near coords, %si lo descomentas sale el valor en cada barra
      nodes near coords style={text=black},
      nodes near coords align={vertical},
      %grid=major %coloca la grilla de fondo
      ]
\addplot[black!20,fill] coordinates {
      (1913,1095) 
      (1923,1398)
      (1930,2205)
      (1937-8,1678)
      (1944-5,1571)
      (1960,391)
      (1971,596)
      };
\addlegendentry{Capital top 100 (USD corrientes)};
\addplot[black,fill]  coordinates {
      (1913,140) 
      (1923,185)
      (1930,706)
      (1937-8,581)
      (1944-5,584)
      (1960,313)
      (1971,565)
      };
\addlegendentry{Capital top 100 industriales (USD corrientes)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{\textbf{Capital 100 mayores EE industriales/capital 100 mayores EE (b)/(a), en millones de USD.} Fuente: \gls{BDEEA}/ \gls{FCAD} PICT 2010/0501. Disponible en \url{http://empexargentina.com}.}\label{figura2-1q}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: The Spanish notation can be achieved with `comma` as in the example `\pgfmathprintnumber
    [fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=5,use comma]
        {12345.6789}` on p. 321 of the pgfplots manual. The other question may only be answered if you provide us with a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a compilable document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I guess that you can adjust the font by replacing `\begin{tikzpicture}` by `\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\cuadrosTTT]` and/or adding `font=\cuadrosTTT` to the options of the axis.

Comment: To obtain Spanish notation in pgfplots (throughout the document), put this in your preamble: `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
   use comma,
   set thousands separator={.},
   fixed}`

Comment: Dear Bibi, thank you for your solution, it is very successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain Spanish notation in `pgfplots` (throughout the document), a solution is to put this in your preamble:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, set thousands separator={.}, fixed}
```

The (numerous) options for number formatting can be found in the `pgfplotstable` documentation (which comes with `pgfplots`). What was used here is explained below.

`use comma`: use comma to separate decimals

`set thousands separator={.}`: self-explanatory

`fixed`: round the number to a fixed number of digits after the period, discarding any trailing zeros